# Installing npm install --save-dev web3@1.0.0-beta.26 error?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to install web3.js library and getting the below issue.

- Node.js 8.x
- Windows 7.

I am able to find python installation under this folder.

> C:\Users\Mabel.windows-build-tools\python27
>
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin
>   \....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program
>    Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python\path\to\executable",
>   you can set the PYTHON env variable.
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mo
>   dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)

---

[image: cmd showing the error on Windows]

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: @hsz yes python installed

Comment: The fact that *you* can find it, doesn't mean npm can. You need to tell it where it is. This is also mentioned in the error message itself: _"Error: Can't find Python executable "python\path\to\executable", **you can set the PYTHON env variable** "_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe

The above command solved the issue.